# Autohotkey Disable or Force Interactions with one Window

Tags: ms-word, autohotkey, disable

My script starts from a textbox window (ms Word document), then it opens a gui window with a button. I need that the textbox window isn't touched until the button is pressed (cause I don't wanna lose the caret position). I see 3 solutions:
1 disabling all the interactions with the textbox window
2 forcing the user to interact only with the gui
3 saving caret position (seems hard)

If you need, that's the code (it creates a tooltip on a text in Microsoft Word):

```
; M i c r o s o f t _ W o r d _ T o o l t i p
;select the main text, then press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+t, then write the tooltip desired then press OK then alt+F9 to hide\unhide the code

^!+t::
;save clipboard
ClipboardA := Clipboard
;various things
Send ^x
Send ^{F9}
Send AutoTextList "
Send ^v
Send " \s No Style \t ""
Send {Ctrl up}{Shift up}{Alt up}{Left}
;save window id
WINDOWID := WinExist("A")
;open gui
gui, add, text, x4 y3, Insert here your tooltip 
gui, add, text, x4 y16, (If code won't hide press Alt+F9)
;add OK button
gui, add, button,default gbuttonOK x173 y0,OK
;add textbox
gui, add, edit, -WantReturn x0 y33 w200 h67 vINPUT,
;select textbox 
GuiControl, Focus, INPUT
;gui parameters
gui, +alwaysontop
gui, show, w200 h100, Insert tooltip
return

;if gui is closed pressing 'x' button               
guiclose:
Clipboard = %ClipboardA%
gui, destroy
return

;if OK is pressed
buttonOK:
;get input from textbox
GuiControlGet, INPUT
;activate Microsoft Word window
WinActivate, ahk_id %WINDOWID%
send %INPUT%
send {F9}
;restore clipboard
Clipboard = %ClipboardA%
;close gui
gui, destroy
return
```

Comment: You can anytime save the caret position on the current active window using the built-in variables [A_CaretX A_CaretY](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Misc).

Comment: thanks, its something, but the carnet coordinates will change if the document gets modified before pressing the button, it would be better to search for a string, but I don't know how search for Xstring + Xinput ( ex. AutoTextList " + %ClipboardB% )

Comment: Would WinHide and WinShow afterwards be a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the textbox window and re-enable it like this:

```
WinSet, Style, +0x8000000, Word ;Disable the window

WinSet, Style, -0x8000000, Word ;Enable the window
```

The caret position will be preserved. Note that you can't focus the window with the mouse while it's disabled.

Comment: The textbox I need to disable is the Microsoft Word document, not the gui textbox made by the script